# R create new column based on if else condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame consisting of `n` column and one of them is `food`. `food` column possible values are `apple`, `tomato`, `cabbage`, `sausage`, `beer`, `vodka`, `potato`. I want to create a new column in my `data` data frame as follows: if `food==apple` or `food==tomato` or `food==potato`, then assign `vegetables`, otherwise assign just `data$food` value.

So, if data frame is like this:

```
ID ..(some other columns).. food

1                           apple
2                           sausage
3                           tomato
4                           cabbage
5                           vodka
```

then the result should be as follows:

```
ID ..(some other columns).. food        category

1                           apple       vegetable
2                           sausage     sausage
3                           tomato      vegetable
4                           cabbage     vegetable
5                           vodka       vodka
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would copy the variable and find which rows correspond to your criterion and replace the values only for those rows. I also added a new factor level for tidy bookkeeping.

```
xy <- data.frame(food = sample(c("apple", "tomato", "cabbage", "sausage", "beer", "vodka", "potato"), 50, replace = TRUE))

xy$newcol <- xy$food
levels(xy$newcol) <- c(levels(xy$newcol), "veggy")
xy[xy$food %in% c("apple", "tomato", "potato"), "newcol"] <- "veggy"
xy

      food  newcol
1    apple   veggy
2    vodka   vodka
3  sausage sausage
4  cabbage cabbage
5    vodka   vodka
6   potato   veggy
7  cabbage cabbage
8  cabbage cabbage
...
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
# df is your data frame
veg <- c("tomato", "apple", "potato")
df$category <- ifelse(df$food %in% veg, "vegetable", df$food)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `recode` from `car`, which will work with both 'character' and 'factor' column.  For 'factor' columns, the unused levels are dropped while new levels are added.

```
library(car)
xy$newcol <- recode(xy$food, "c('apple', 'tomato', 'potato')='veggy'")
```

NOTE: `xy` from @Roman Lustrik's post

If you are using `data.table`, this can be done with (updating the same column)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(xy), food)[J(c('apple', 'tomato', 'potato')), food:='veggy']
```